# Indexing 3D arrays with Numpy

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have an array in three dimensions (x, y, z) and an indexing vector. This vector has a size equal to the dimension x of the array. Its objective is to index a specific y bringing their respective z, i.e., the expected result has dimension (x, z).

I wrote a code that works as expected, but does anyone know if a Numpy function can replace the for loop and solve the problem more optimally?

```
arr = np.random.rand(100,5,2)
result = np.random.rand(100,2)
id = [np.random.randint(0, 5) for _ in range(100)]
for i in range(100): 
    result[i] = arr[i,id[i]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with this piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randn(100, 5, 2)
ids = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=100)
res = arr[range(100), ids]
res.shape # (100, 2)
```

Comment: Not sure if OP meant to only index the y dimension. If so the first dimension will not be indexed: ```res = arr[:, ids]```.